# Use of NOT where also using OR

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, operator-precedence

If used in a complex set of arguments, does the NOT condition apply only to the first argument or to all subsequent arguments?

e.g. In the following fragment of a merge statement does the NOT operator only apply to the

`TGT.OrderID = SRC.OrderID` argument?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx advises that NOT is evaluated before OR. 
Does that mean that it is applied to all arguments or that I need a new one for every argument being negated - in which case I would need to add one to the fourth and seventh arguments.

```
WHEN MATCHED AND NOT TGT.OrderID = SRC.OrderID 
              OR(TGT.OrderID IS NULL AND SRC.OrderID IS NOT NULL)
              OR(TGT.OrderID IS NOT NULL AND SRC.OrderID IS NULL)
              OR TGT.EmpID = SRC.EmpID
              OR(TGT.EmpID IS NULL AND SRC.EmpID IS NOT NULL) 
              OR(TGT.EmpID IS NOT NULL AND SRC.EmpID IS NULL) 
              OR TGT.orderdate = SRC.OrderDate
              OR(TGT.Orderdate IS NULL AND SRC.Orderdate IS NOT NULL)
              OR(TGT.Orderdate IS NOT NULL AND SRC.Orderdate IS NULL)
```

Comment: You need parentheses if you want it to apply to a compound expression.

Comment: Wherever you have confusion, just add parentheses. `OR` creates a whole new expression, superceding `AND`, unless you parenthesize it. `A AND B OR C` means `(A AND B) OR C`, it does NOT mean `A AND (B OR C)`. Similarly, `NOT A OR B` means `(NOT A) OR B`, but you can add parentheses to make it `NOT (A OR B)`. Note that `NOT (A OR B)` is the same as `NOT A AND NOT B`.

Comment: Got it. Post that as an answer so I can accept it. Many thanks.

Comment: When I'm mixing `and` and `or`, I *always* use parentheses. No shame in that, I think.

Comment: Maybe not exactly about the question, but I see some pattern in your code. I assume that you want to do action when columns are matched and one of column OrderId, EmpID, orderdate is different between SRC and TARGET. You can rewrite it AS `WHEN MATCHED AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT SRC.OrderID, SRC.EmpId, SRC.OrderDate INTERSECT SELECT TGT.OrderId, TGT.EmpID, TGT.orderdate)` and get rid of that nasty NOT, AND, OR combo. More info: [IS DISTINCT FROM predicate workaround in TSQL](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx).

Comment: Aside: From the Department of Unexpected Results: `select 30/2/5; select 30/-2/5; select 30/-2./5; select 30/(-2)/5;`. See [here](http://w3facility.org/question/sql-server-strange-math-result/) for more information. A change in _documented_ operator precedence between [SQL Server 2000](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276846%28v=sql.80%29) and [2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) makes this reasonable, if rather unconventional.

Answer (score 3):

"NOT is evaluated before OR" means that the NOT operator has precedence over the OR, which means it will negate the statement that immediately follows, in this case "TGT.OrderID = SRC.OrderID". After that, the interpreter will perform the OR statements.

Think of it as -A + B. The - only affects A, not B. If you want -A + -B, you have to do that or you can use parentheses to change the evaluation oder, e.g. -(A + B)

Answer (score 0):

Operator precedence https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx

the order of evaluation of AND, OR, and NOT is:

- `NOT`
- `AND`
- `OR`

What this means is that if you have a predicate like:
`NOT A AND B OR C AND NOT D`
this happens:
`NOT` is applied first:

`(NOT A) AND B OR C AND (NOT D)`

`AND` applied next:

`((NOT A) AND B) OR (C AND (NOT D))`

`OR` is applied last

**`(((NOT A) AND B) OR (C AND (NOT D)))`**

If two have the same precedence, it is applied from left to right.

`A AND B AND C AND D`

Becomes the following:

1. `(A AND B) AND C AND D`
2. `((A AND B) AND C) AND D`
3. **`(((A AND B) AND C) AND D)`**

The complexity of your predicate does not change this order, and in case you do want a different order, you can always use parenthesis explicitly.